# Copy to S3 with AWS CLI with proper content type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, content-type

I'm deploying static AngularJS webpage to S3 bucket. I use Jenkins, copy file over Shell with AWS CLI. The specific command in Groovy looks like this:

```groovy
// after build, files are located in frontend/target/myfrontend/
sh 'aws s3 cp frontend/target/myfrontend/ $FrontendAddress --recursive'
```

I have SVG graphics in `/resources` folder. That image is not displayed correctly inside `img` tag, because it has content-type set by default to `binary/octet-stream`. It should be `image/svg+xml` instead.

How to copy my SVG files with `aws s3 cp` command, and set correct content type?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The command to change content type for *.svg files is:

```
aws s3 cp --content-type image/svg+xml --acl public-read $FrontendAddress/resources/ $FrontendAddress/resources/ --metadata-directive REPLACE --exclude "*" --include "*.svg" --recursive
```

Comment: Here is the official document: "If REPLACE is used, the copied object will only have the metadata values that were specified by the CLI command. Note that if you are using any of the following parameters: --content-type, content-language, --content-encoding, --content-disposition, --cache-control, or --expires, you will need to specify --metadata-directive REPLACE for non-multipart copies if you want the copied objects to have the specified metadata values." ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html )

Comment: Note that `--acl public-read` isn't necessary to change the content type.

Answer (score 11):

```
aws s3 sync _site/ s3://BUCKET --delete --exclude '*.svg'
aws s3 sync _site/ s3://BUCKET --delete --exclude '*' --include '*.svg' --content-type 'image/svg+xml'
```